# Fill a column with dates for two days per week

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, google-sheets-dates

I need to keep track of an employee who works Mondays and Thursdays. I need to fill a column with dates for these days. I know how to do sequential dates and I have tried dragging down from the corner on a series of manually entered dates, but this does not work, presumable because there is a 3-day gap, then a two-day gap. The column looks like this (European date format):

Monday, 2 10 2023

Thursday, 5 10 2023

Monday, 9 10 2023

Thursday, 12 10 2023

... etc.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get Mondays and Thursdays in the next `4` weeks starting on `2023-10-02`, use this:

```
=let( 
  dates, sequence(4 * 7, 1, "2023-10-02"), 
  filter( 
    to_date(dates), 
    match(weekday(dates, 2), vstack(1, 4), 0) 
  ) 
)
```

This uses a convention where Monday is weekday `1`, Thursday is `4` and Sunday is `7`.

See
[let()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535),
[sequence()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244),  [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197),
[vstack()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13191461)
and
[match()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378).